# Is it possible to recover the unsaved notepad and paint file after the computer rebooting from the blue screen of death?

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod

When my computer was idling, it turns into black screen and then the blue screen of death came up with the error code INTERNAL_POWER_ERROR. After the computer rebooted, I open the application for notepad and paint and I found that two unsaved notepad and several unsaved paint files were gone despite they were all properly recovered when windows automatically restarted for update a while ago.

Is it still possible to recover the files?

Comment: There is the possibility that if the computer was configured to create a complete or active dump and you let it complete writing the dump, that C:\windows\memory.dmp has the "data".  I'm not saying its super easy to retrieve, but this could be the only place the data is. I would first check your computer's dump type.  I'm pretty sure it's not complete or active by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because there's no files to recover.
If you open a file in Notepad or Paint, the file is uploaded to your RAM memory and all changes are made to the copy in RAM.
When the computer crashes the RAM are wiped clean.

When windows automatically restarts it's not a crash, but a controlled restart and windows actually saves all microsoft files for you.
As both notepad and paint are microsoft programs, windows will save these for you.
If you had used a non-microsoft program, like GIMP, the work wouln'd been saved.

Comment: Is it possible to get the files saved during the previous restart are somehow still saved?