# Where Windows 11 update keep a backup of unsaved Notepad window (specially before update that requires restart)?

Tags: windows, windows-11, notepad, notepad2, windows-11-v22h2

On Windows 11, I had an OS update (while I was not there) and PC restarted automatically, and I found that any unsaved Notepad window was kept with its content as is. (which means Windows has stored backup of it somewhere)

The problem I'm facing now is that after a while, an electricity cut off happened and PC turned off before I save any unsaved Notepad window. 
After turning on the PC, I couldn't find my Notepad windows restored.

I need to know where Windows 11 keeps a backup of the content of unsaved Notepad windows (like the one kept before Windows update) so hopefully I can restore my Notepad window.

---

My question may look similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1715847/is-it-possible-to-recover-the-unsaved-notepad-and-paint-file-after-the-computer), but I'm asking specifically for the path or place where Windows update saves a backup for unsaved Notepad window's content before update restart (hopefully I could retrieve my lost Notepad windows' content, even partially to the time of the update restart happened).

Comment: @John I think Windows.old file/folder is dedicated for major upgrade (which my question isn't concerned about).
I'm focused on minor updates that requires restart after which unsaved Notepad windows are preserved. I need to know where Windows could store/save these windows' contents.

Comment: Update orchestration now is specifically designed to prevent loss of data, as had often occurred in the past, and intentionally saves data before shutting down and rebooting. This requires the power to be connected, of course. There *are* applications, such as MS Word, that will save data periodically to a backup file, but not Notepad. AFAIK, your data has gone to the Null device in the sky.

Comment: No Backup, no mercy...  use Notepad++ (yes, I know, this answer sucks, I had to learn the hard way as well)